# Listing links in insertion order in rational DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a module A with objects linked *from* objects in another module B. In a view of A, I have a layout DXL column which lists all those linked B objects:

```
// DXL generated by DOORS traceability wizard on 02 May 2016.
// Wizard version 2.0, DOORS version 9.2.0.5
pragma runLim, 0
string limitModules[1] = {"40fedbf2697f0e24-00003921"}

void showIter(Object o, string linkModName, int depth, string build, string iter) {
        Link l
        Object othero
        for l in all(o<-linkModName) do {   // ****
            otherVersion = sourceVersion l
            otherMod = module(otherVersion)
            if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
            if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[depth-1]))) continue
            othero = source l
            if (null othero) {
                load(otherVersion,false)
            }
            othero = source l
            if (null othero) continue
            if (isDeleted othero) continue
            doneOne = true
            if (depth == 1) {
                disp = ""
                obuild = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Build", false)
                oiter = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Iteration (planned)", false)
                string ocat = othero."Category"
                if (obuild == build && oiter == iter) {
                    s = "(B" obuild "." oiter " - " ocat[0] ") " (identifier othero)
                    disp = disp s
                    s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Object Text", false)
                    disp = disp  " " s
                    displayRich("\\pard " disp)
                }
            }
        }
}

void showIn(Object o, int depth) {
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    Item linkModItem = itemFromID("40fedbf2697f0e24-000039a3")
    if (null linkModItem) {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Link module not found>>")
    } else if (type(linkModItem) != "Link") {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Invalid link module index for this database>>")
    } else {
        string linkModName = fullName(linkModItem)
        for lr in all(o<-linkModName) do {
            otherMod = module (sourceVersion lr)
            if (!null otherMod) {
                if ((!isDeleted otherMod) && (null data(sourceVersion lr))) {
                    if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[depth-1]))) continue
                    load((sourceVersion lr),false)
                }
            }
        }
        //showIter(o, linkModName, depth, "1", "")
        //showIter(o, linkModName, depth, "2", "")
        showIter(o, linkModName, depth, "3", "3")
    }
}
showIn(obj,1)
```

This script lists the linked objects in numerical order by object ID/key:

```
B object with ID# 3
B object with ID# 8
B object with ID# 21
B object with ID# 24
```

Yet in module B, without any sorting active, the objects are visible in insertion order, like this (i.e. according to where I made the insertion):

```
B object with ID# 24
B object with ID# 8
B object with ID# 21
B object with ID# 3
```

Is there a way to loop over B objects in insertion order, i.e. in order that they are displayed in B view when no sorting is active?

Answer (score 0):

A "natural" order as you define it, is the order in which the source objects appear in the source module. This does not cover the case where source objects come from different modules, but this is just another problem..

A loop “.. for l in ....” has by definition no order defined, so in case you need one, you have to define your own order. In DXL, this is usually done by Skip lists.

You can create a skip list with the key being of type integer or string and the value being of type Link.
Then for each link, you can somehow calculate the correct order and add an entry where the key represents the order to the Skip list. A later loop „for l in skip“ will process the skip list in the order of the keys.

In your case, you can calculate the key by using a loop over all source objects, with the aid of a temporary skip list, like

```
int order = 0
Skip skOrderOfObject = create()
Object o
for o in entire (... source module...) do {
    order ++
    int absno = o."Absolute Number"
    put (skOrderOfObject, order, absno)
}
```

Then to process each source object in your DXL column, you can do a

```
Skip skMySortedLinks = create()
...
for l in... {
    Object oSource = source l
    int iOrderOfThisObject
    int absnoOfSource = oSource."Absolute Number"
    find (skOrderOfObject, absnoOfSource, iOrderOfThisObject);
    put (skMySortedLinks, iOrderOfThisObject, l)
}
```

and finally

```
Link l
for l in skMySortedLinks do {
    ... print whatever you want to print...
}
```

Comment: By "natural" I meant the order they appear in when you open the module, when sorting is off, i.e. insertion order. The order of loop in DXL is by object ID. I have updated my answer, please take another look because the skip list seems unlikely to be practical solution AFAICT.

Comment: updated my post after re-reading your question. A skip list may not look elegant or fast, but I do not see a different solution. The order in which links „appear“ in the target module have no connection to the order in which the source objects exist in the source module, so you have to insert your own logic.

Comment: Interesting. The key assumption is that `for o in entire (... source module...) do` iterates over objects in insertion order, i.e. in order in which they appear in module. I will try this out. One thing: of the 3 pieces of code you list, the first only needs to be run once for the B module, but is this possible? If I put the first piece in the A column DXL, the skOrderOfObject will be regenerated for *every* A object (that has links from B).

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I got no email about the comment.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I got no email about the comment, hoping that this is still relevant for someone.
Sharing code between several dxl contexts is possible but not trivial. See e.g. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0a1dc1ee-cd96-411e-9e19-f53899e7ffd7 or https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=2e998269-ded8-4a47-b350-ca0a2e879113